# Can I create the REST API of my application on azure and link them with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, azure, sublimetext2

I have a "web app" on azure with laravel framowork. If I create the REST API using the "api management service" in php, how do I retrieve them from laravel? It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

As Laravel doesn't have any built-in HTTP request package you may consider the following options to retrieve data from REST API.

- [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

  ```
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://url_to_the_api'));
  ```
- [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

  ```
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle');
  echo $res->getStatusCode();
  // 200
  echo $res->getHeaderLine('content-type');
  // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
  echo $res->getBody();
  // '{"id": 1420053, "name": "guzzle", ...}'

  // Send an asynchronous request.
  $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org');
  $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
      echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
  });
  $promise->wait();
  ```

I personally prefer to use the Guzzle which can easily integrate with Laravel, you can check out [@Mohammed Safeer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124018/laravel-retrieving-data-from-rest-api/32569675#32569675) for details.